# Prevent Datatable collapsing

Tags: datatable, datatables

When there are rows which didnt fit in screen datatable collapses and display button + .So I want to datatable should fit to screen and show all rows.

Comment: Disable responsive plugin then, and set `scrollX: true` in datatable config. There is no option to make it so all rows fit on scren even if they don't fit, that makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes it is possible and its very easy use**

Please follow the link [click here](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/column-control/column-visibility.html)

You have to include this JS https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js

And use datatable like below

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {

  responsive: true

} );
```

Comment: I have already using but issue is in reponsive it collapses one column as there is space in which it fit easily. so I dont want to collapse that column.